# 3.3V Buck-boost converter outputting voltage too high

Tags: switching-regulator, 3.3v, buck-boost

I'm using a buck-boost converter [RT6150B](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT6150A=RT6150B/DS6150AB-05.pdf) with fixed 3V3 output. I followed their application notes, and here's my circuit setup:
[image]
Note: I used 22uF for C4 intead of the recommended 20uF for output capacitor. I couldn't find a good SM component for 20uF and I thought 22uF is close enough.

Testing condition: I made a small test PCB based on this schematic, and I used a external power supply to feed different input voltage levels into the IC. From Vin = 3.1V-4.2V, Vout was kept pretty stable around 3.9V (Iout~20mA), which is too high comparing to the expected 3V3 output. When I try lower Vin = 3V, Vout dropped significantly to around 1.7V (Iout~140mA).I can also hear very small buzzing sound from the IC when I was testing with it.

There are several issues here, but first of all I don't get why the output voltage is around 3.9V instead of 3.3V? I used the recommended inductor value from the datasheet for generating 3V3 at output. Other things are just capacitors to decrease the voltage ripples. I really don't know what is causing this issue.

Any help is appreciated!

[Update]
Here's the screenshot for Vout:
[image]
(Sorry for the bad quality. Had to take the picture with my phone...)

Comment: What is the load on your test PCB?

Comment: Are you sure you have the fixed version and not the adjustable version?

Comment: His FB is connected to VOUT which tells the chip fixed mode.

Comment: Clarifying load question: is that a 3.3V LED?

Comment: How closely does your PCB follow the layout guide on page 11 of the datasheet?

Comment: Currently the load is just the LED, which is where the ~20mA Iout came from I think. I tried adding another load of a 90 ohm resistor, and it just added ~40mA more current to the output.

Comment: The LED has Vf = 2.1V @20mA

Comment: Minimum load requirements?

Comment: DC current spec for L1?

Comment: I think the layout guide is for having GND on the same layer from the IC. I used the bottom layer of the PCB as the ground plane, so I just placed vias for accessing GND. But other than that, I followed their guidelines, such as keeping the inductor close and placing the capacitors close to Vin and Vout pins.

Comment: It says current rating is 30mA for the inductor. Also datasheet here: https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/inductor_automotive_standard_mlf1608_en.pdf

Comment: @winny I didn't see the datasheet mentioning about minimum  load requirements for the IC...

Comment: Sounds to me like your output is oscillating maybe due to layout.  What does the output voltage look like on a scope?  Like @JohnBirckhead said the inductor datasheet would also be important to look at.

Comment: A 30mA inductor sounds pretty undersized.  Is anything getting hot to the touch?  Also, like @JohnD mentioned, getting a few scope captures will be very helpful.

Comment: Also, is this a PCB or did you rig it up by hand?  Have you tested more than one?  More often than not, I discover that weird power supply behaviors like this are caused by solder issues (cold solder or shorts)

Comment: Just curious. But are you absolutely sure you got the RT6150B-33GQW? They do make a variable output version, RT6150BGQW. Can you verify the complete part number?

Comment: @jonk Yes. I'm sure the one I have is the fixed output version. Double-checked the marking on the IC based on datasheet Page 2.

Comment: @Selvek I did realize afterwards that the current rating for my inductor is pretty small, and I am planning to change it later, but I think for this case it should be sufficient to support the LED current. It does not explain the 3.9V output still.

Comment: Because your inductor is turning into a simple wire when the core is saturated. The max coil current is 2 or 3 times higher than the load current in switched mode.

Comment: @Selvek Also I had the traces cut out by machine and soldered the components by myself. Did continuity tests for all connections and it seemed fine. For now I tested two boards that behaved the same way. I'll probably make a few new boards to replace the inductor, but I want to first make sure there's no other issues component-wise.

Comment: I also hope that you noticed the frequency. The coil must work at 1.2Mhz. And the capacitors to.

Comment: Dorian I'm not sure if I followed what you said. Is the inductor saturated when I have Iout of the IC bigger than the inductor's current rating? I checked the inductance VS frequency graph from the datasheet. The inductor seems like it has the normal 2.2uH @1MHz.

Comment: Iout through LED  is an average of the Icoil . Icoil has peaks 2, 3 times higher or even more.

Comment: What's your peak current at the end of the switch cycle? Is it more than 30 mA? If yes, you are in a bad spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit will likely work with an inductor with an appropriate current rating.  Remember that the load current is the average of the current in the inductor.  The current has a triangle waveform; in boost mode, the inductor is switched to ground to "charge up" the inductor until its current is greater than that required by the load.  Then the switch is opened and the inductor is current is dumped into the load, with the current decreasing as the inductor "discharges:"

[image]

In buck mode, The voltage input voltage is higher than the output and the inductor charges up while the supply is connected to the load through the inductor.  The supply is then disconnected and the inductor current must flow through the diode.  Since the inductor has a negative voltage, the current decreases:

[image]

The inductor B_H Curve looks like this:

[image]

The operating range of the inductor must be in the relatively linear area.  Since the inductor only has current flowing in one direction, it must operate in the upper right quadrant only.  The area marked "minor B-H loop" would be acceptable, with the BH loop sliding up and down the curve as the inductor charges and discharges.  However, too much current will drive the operating region up into the non-linear part of the curve.  The inductance is not constant in this area and it will drop and change value at different points in the boost or buck cycle.

In boost mode, the inductor must store enough energy on each charge cycle (1/2Li^2) to provide average power on the discharge cycle.  You just don't have enough core to do this when L drops due to saturation, and the result is too low voltage.

In buck mode, the inductance drops during the charge cycle, causing a current surge into your load and capacitor and fully charging your inductor.  The load must then discharge the inductor during the time before the next charge cycle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think now I understand that for boost mode, because my inductor can't store enough energy, my Vout  results in very low voltage like the ~1.7V that I was getting. But for the buck mode, I still don't quite understand how the inductor results in the higher voltage level like 3.9V at Vout? Why would the inductance drops during charging?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think now I understand that for boost mode, because my inductor can't store enough energy, my Vout  results in very low voltage like the ~1.7V that I was getting. But for the buck mode, I still don't quite understand how the inductor results in the higher voltage level like 3.9V at Vout? Why would the inductance drops during charging?

Comment: Even for buck mode the peak current might be twice as the average output current to avoid switching while the coil is still charged for efficiency resons. In the B-graph the slope is the coil inductance, over 30mA you are getting into the flat region , zero inductance and the current raises extremly fast so the switchoff is not fast enough to avoid a current peak getting to output.

Comment: It is not really clear to me either - the buck mode reason is more dependent on your switching IC and is more complex.  But in general, in buck mode, if you are saturating on each cycle, the inductor voltage will drop to near zero and the output will rise quickly.  It would be interesting to see if your voltage decreases when you reduce the load.

Comment: Finally got to test it with a new inductor! Used one with a 700mA current rating, and the circuit was able to give me ~3.3V voltage output.

Comment: Very nice!  Congrats